# Not able to take backup of exisitng folder

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

what i am trying to do here is,i have a directory called **mind** and i want promp the user to give input the name of the directory for which he want to take a backup. So user will give input here as **mind**. I am copying **mind** in the same directory just renaming it as a **mind_todaysdatatime**. But it's not working for me. Before this when i was manually specifying the directory name it was working for me. But after making changes to my code for user to prompt the directory of which he wants to take a backup was not working for me.
Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter a orgname"

read $org


cd /tibco/data/GRISSOM2/$org

echo "!! Following directory structure have been deployed to your internal enterprise!!"


 echo "==================="
  cp -r /tibco/data/GRISSOM2/mind /tibco/data/GRISSOM2/$org$( date +%d%m%Y%H%M )

 echo "===================="
```

Before this when **$org$( date +%d%m%Y%H%M )** was like **mind$( date +%d%m%Y%H%M )**  was working,but now it is not working. How do we go about it?

The output it is giving me is only the datetime folder like **270720131258** expected is **mind270720131258**. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way you've read the variable `org`.

```
read $org
```

Should be

```
read org
```

The way you're doing it, org will not be set to anything.